# embedding media with max proportional size

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I'm using a web view to preview different kinds of files (pdf, images, videos)
I don't know the type of media item at that time - I just have the local path of it.

And I want to make sure that its max width is 1000 and max height is 770 - sizing it down proportionally when its larger.
So I tried to compose an HTML snipped to embed the media item into the web view:

```
<embed style='align=center; vertical-align:middle;max-width=1000; max-height=770;' src='file://localpath_to_file'>
</embed>
```

But that does not size a larger image down.
I tried to enclose the embed tag within div tags and applied the style to those - did not help either.
Any hints ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you replace the equals = with colon.

`<embed style="align:center; vertical-align:middle;max-width:1000; max-height:770;" src="file://localpath_to_file">
</embed>`

Give it a try =)

Comment: stupid misstake - thanks. the align:center did not work as expected though. On competent advise I enclosed the <embed> within good old <center> tags - thank works well. thanks